# What are the different names of "canvas chair"?

Tags: nouns

I call chairs like this

[image: A foldable chair, upholstered in blue synthetic material with a black border. It has a cup holder made from black netting embedded in the right arm.]

"canvas chairs".

But I'm not sure if this is the proper name.

Are there other names for this type of chair in America, Britain, and other English-speaking countries?

Comment: I might call it a "camping chair" or a "camp chair" or a "*collapsible camp chair*"   http://www.rei.com/c/camping-chairs

Comment: just on a related note, there's a "director's chair" which, fortunately, has a clear definition (just google images).

Comment: further to be clear, Zack, I WOULD NOT call this a "canvas chair". "canvas chair" has a pretty clear meaning, just google image it.  Canvas chairs come in two types, the square ones, or the "sunbathing" lay down ones.  (Also as a minor issue, the "camping chair" you refer to are not at all made of canvas.)

Answer (score 3):

[Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/DNP-Legal-Issue-Ozark-Trail-Deluxe-Folding-Camping-Arm-Chair/23864494) seems to list a similar chair as ***Camping chair***, or more specifically, *Camping Arm Chair.*

This picture, *taken from the source linked above*, looks very much the same as the one in your description:

[image: A foldable chair, upholstered in red synthetic material with a black border. It has a cup holder made from black netting embedded in the right arm.]

Searching for ***Quad chair***, again on [Walmart,](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Coleman-Oversized-Quad-Chair-with-Cooler-Pouch/20594238) gives an almost similar looking chair. Picture below *taken from the Walmart site linked here*:

[image: (from the walmart description) Coleman Oversized Quad Chair with Cooler Pouch: *Padded seat and back. *Soft cooler pouch (3" x 8" x 8") holds 2 - 4 cans and 1 Coleman Chiller (small). *Mesh cup holder. *Program holder (13" x 9") *Adjustable arm height. *Oversize dimensions: 37"W x 24"D x 40.5"H. *Brown]

Answer (score 2):

While probably more commonly known as a camping chair, it's also known as a "bag chair", as shown in the product [description](http://www.swimoutlet.com/ProductDetails.asp?subscribe=Y&ProductCode=21070&gclid=CjwKEAjwp7WgBRCRxMCLx8mMnDMSJADncxS2N3QoSvPDo7tgFZfVMvBfcgbJJzkBhzlr1dK927ydCxoClODw_wcB) on Swimoutlet.com:

[image: Wet products bag chair]

It differentiates from a director's chair in that a director's chair is foldable  but not collapsible to the point that it can fit in a tube-shaped bag.

"Bag chair" is also sometimes used to categorize bean bag chairs which are not collapsible and are filled with foam "beads":

[image: picture from www.johnstonefitness.com of a woman lounging in a large, dark teal beanbag]

Answer (score 0):

Another popular term for such chairs is  *slingback chairs*.  The picture below, from scenicmesa.com, is named (in part) sling-back-chair...jpg on that site.  Note, as seen via [A chair made from metal poles bound by wires, upholsters in what looks like leather](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1154&bih=650&q=slingback+chairs&oq=slingback+ch&gs_l=img.1.0.0l2j0i5j0i24l7.2484.8641.0.11480.12.11.0.1.1.0.211.912.9j1j1.11.0....0...1ac.1.53.img..0.12.906.EQsOyxvtDEw#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=CTMV784a3QoOzM%253A%3B6jkZt87zadVVqM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.scenicmesa.com%252Fmedia%252FProducts%252Fsling-back-chair-FDA75FB1-9BC8-591E-8A7A155B345777DB-zoomed.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.scenicmesa.com%252Fbuffalo-chairs-ottomans%252Fsling-back-chair%252F%3B1020%3B1170),  *slingback chairs* encompasses a broad range of fabric- or leather-sling chairs.

[image: slingback chair]